# Why doesnt a new div appear when i click the button

Tags: javascript, html

Its a project for adding pictures and i want to create more picture loading boxes **before the add box** when the button with 'add' class is pressed. When the button is pressed the console log works but the change of innerHTML doesnt. As i am a beginner i would appriciate any comments that can improve my work as im trying to learn and grow everyday. thank you!

here is the html, css and js:

```js
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')
const add = document.getElementsByClassName('add')


function addMore(){
    container.innerHTML += `
    <div class="box upload">
        <div class="cir">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-upload fa-2xl" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    `
    console.log('done')
}
```

```css
body {
    background: rgb(112,50,154);
    background: linear-gradient(158deg, rgba(112,50,154,1) 9%, rgba(29,126,253,1) 100%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}

.box{
    background-color: rgb(100, 0, 100);
    border: 1px solid rgb(183, 79, 183);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 157px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px ;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.add {
    opacity: 70%;
}

.cir {
    background-color: rgba(250, 235, 215, 0.408);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>App</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9f2b728e62.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box upload">
            <div class="cir">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-upload fa-2xl" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="box add" onclick="addMore()">
            <div class="cir">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-plus fa-fade fa-2xl" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
            </div>
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an html collection. `const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];`

Comment: Or the more modern `const container = document.querySelector(".container")`

Comment: [Don't use `.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474).

Comment: @epascarello how can i add the div before the adding div

Comment: don't put the button in the div, put it after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object

more info about it here [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

You have to access the element by its index so add [0] to it since you only have one element with that class so you have to access that element like this

```
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]
```

or in this case is better if you use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
```

**Edit**: Edited the HTML to have your button at the beggining and your first div right next to it (it looks better)

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const add = document.querySelector('.add')


function addMore() {
  container.innerHTML += `
    <div class="box upload">
        <div class="cir">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-upload fa-2xl" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    `
  console.log('done')
}
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(112, 50, 154);
  background: linear-gradient(158deg, rgba(112, 50, 154, 1) 9%, rgba(29, 126, 253, 1) 100%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.box {
  background-color: rgb(100, 0, 100);
  border: 1px solid rgb(183, 79, 183);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 157px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.add {
  opacity: 70%;
}

.cir {
  background-color: rgba(250, 235, 215, 0.408);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>App</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9f2b728e62.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button class="box add" onclick="addMore()">
        <div class="cir">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-plus fa-fade fa-2xl" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
        </div>
      </button>
    <div class="box upload">
      <div class="cir">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-upload fa-2xl" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but doesn't include the warning to [not use `.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) in any case and instead use `.querySelector()` or `.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: makes sense, no point using `getElementsByClassName` when he just wants the one and only element present in the document, edited my answer and used `querySelector` on the `add` button as well

Comment: It's actually a bit more than just needing one element. `.getElementsByClassName()` is a legacy API that has performance implications and really should be avoided all the time.

Answer (score 0):

[document.getElementsByClassName()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) returns an HTMLCollection which is accessed like an array. You want to modify the first element in that array like this:

```
function addMore(){
    container[0].innerHTML += `
    <div class="box upload">
        <div class="cir">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-upload fa-2xl" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    `
    console.log('done')
}
```

Comment: it is not an array

Comment: Fair point. It is still accessed similarly to an array. I have updated the answer.

Comment: no? it is a live HTMLCollection

Comment: W3schools claims it is an HTML collection. Of course they could be wrong.